# I was trying to display my data in JSON format when I run the Springboot application. But gives me an error something like this [{},{},{},{},{},{}]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, spring-data-jpa

So, the problem was that I was trying to display my content in JSON format by connecting my Spring application and Postgres SQL, After trying multiple times I was unable to figure out what was wrong with my application such that it couldn't display the data.
Can anyone help me with this?[[[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyQzo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeexk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0gmY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxMuN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NJ0b.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/146kv.png)

I tried to resolve the error but seems like im getting error like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmZvz.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding getter and setter methods for the query params defined in the Question.class file and also verify whether the names are same as the column names.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).